# How to change the local port number in Policy center v10?

Tags: gosu, guidewire

I have been tried couple of configuration files but not able to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my self finally.

Go to **`PolicyCenter\.idea\runConfigurations\server.xml`** and change the port as you want as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Yes this is the right way: Go to PolicyCenter\.idea\runConfigurations\server.xml

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing **"Run/Debug configurations"** in Guidewire Studio?

[image]

In Policy Center v8.0.4 there is a VM parameter **"-Dgw.port="** to specify port number.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.